# List of substring matching with file name- python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to match the filename by passing a list of substrings to avoid some files in loop if the string matches with the filename. Here's my code:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('D:/folder/*.gz') # create the list of file
mylist=['abcd11','abcd12','jklm12','wxyz.12']
for file_name in list_of_files:
   for ind in df.index:
        if df['filename'][ind] in file_name: #filename column contains full file names 
            for i in mylist:
                if i not in file_name:
                    print(file_name)
```

The thing is, it is also returning filenames which are matching with those list items.
following code is working if I pass only one substring in for loop, but I want to match multiple substrings to avoid multiple files.

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('D:/folder/*.gz') # create the list of file
for file_name in list_of_files:
   for ind in df.index:
        if df['filename'][ind] in file_name: #filename column contains full file names 
            if 'abcd11' not in file_name:
                    print(file_name)
```

Sorry if this kind of question is already been asked. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be like this:

```
list_of_files = glob.glob('D:/folder/*.gz') # create the list of file
mylist=['abcd11','abcd12','jklm12','wxyz.12']
for file_name in list_of_files:
   for ind in df.index:
        if df['filename'][ind] in file_name: #filename column contains full file names 
            is_in_list = False
            for i in mylist:
                if i in file_name:
                    is_in_list = True
            if not is_in_list:
                print(file_name)
```

The problem with your code is that if the condition:

```
if i not in file_name:
```

Is satisfied for one of the elements in `mylist`, then it will print the name of the file. Whereas, what you want is that it is satisfied for **all** elements in `mylist`.

Comment: Hello, @Bruno Mello Thanks for your time! I tried the above code but this one also satisfied for one element (first in the loop) in mylist instead for all elements.